# How to prove that eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix with respect to a metric are real, and that there always exists an eigenbasis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$\lambda_i M\mathbf{v}_i=K\mathbf{v}_i$$

$K$ is a real symmetric matrix and $M$ is real and diagonal.

I need to prove that the eigenvalues of $K$ with respect to the metric $M$ are real, that eigenvectors for different eigenvalues are orthogonal with respect to the metric (i.e $\mathbf{v}^T_iM\mathbf{v}_j=0$ if $i\ne j$) and that there exists an orthonormal eigenbasis.

I've managed to prove the orthogonality of eigenvectors with different eigenvalues, but am struggling with the other two proofs.

Hints would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Metric is the termonology used in the text I'm reading. To clear up any confusion, let me make it clear that $M$ is a diagonal, real matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say $M$ is a metric.  Do you mean $M$ is a *matrix*?

Comment: $M^{-1}K$ is real symmetric and therefore diagonalizable as required, isn't it?

Comment: $M^{-1}K$ might not be symmetric, but $M^{-1/2} K M^{-1/2}$ should be.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C=M^{-1/2}$ (the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the reciprocals of the square roots of the diagonal entries of $M$). Then $C=C^*$ and $C^*MC=E$ (the identity matrix), and if we seek the eigenvectors in the form $v_i=Cu_i$, then the problem for the $u_i$ becomes $C^*KCu_i=\lambda_i u_i$. The matrix $C^*KC$ is real and symmetric, and so its eigenvalues are real and there exists an orthonormal eigenbasis $\{u_i\}$ (with respect to the standard inner product on $R^n$). The vectors $v_i=Cu_i$ are then orthogonal in the metric defined by $M$.